# how to use different environment file for publishing other than appsetting.json?

Tags: c#, dockerfile, environment-variables, production-environment, appsettings

I have 3 environment file in .Net project i.e. appsetting.json, appsetting.Development.json & appsetting.UAT.json.

I wanted to publish my project with UAT environment rather than appsetting.json on a different port.

how should I configure it so that it picks variables from appsetting.UAT.json instead of appsetting.json in DockerFile?

Comment: Use the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` variable in your deployed environment and the app will then consume the appropriately-named file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Comment: `"UAT Env": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "UAT"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5002"
    }`

this is how I have added the environment in launchSetting.json.
but I am not sure, how to call script in dockerfile to pick UAT environment? @MartinCostello

`# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
COPY ./Emails ./out/Emails`